# Django model field: Checking "if field is not None" vs. "if field"

Tags: python, django

Is there a meaningful difference between

```
if self.pk is not None:
```

and

```
if self.pk:
```

when checking a model field in python django?

Other languages have all kinds of differing 'correct' ways to check for a variable being null, empty, nonexistant, whatever.

a) I don't know how python handles the check

b) I don't know if this is important and / or meaningful in the context of django model fields

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first check is checking that the primary key is not [`None`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html#None). The second is checking that the primary key is [truthy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#truth-value-testing). So yes, there is a difference.

Answer (score 1):

`Pk` is a [property](https://github.com/django/django/blob/1.7/django/db/models/base.py#L515) that usually resolves to `id`. There is no magic other than that.

So the only difference between the two statements is how Python treats them. The first one explicitely tests if `pk` is None, whereas the second one will pass for any ["falsy" value](https://docs.python.org/release/2.5.2/lib/truth.html) of `pk`.

Note that `pk` shouldn't usually evaluate to `False` unless the model instance is not saved to the database, so in practice the two statements should be pretty much equivalent.